# Como pasar valores de un subquery a otro queryset?

Tags: python, django

Hola buenas tardes me podrían apoyar con la siguiente duda.

Tengo el siguiente Model:

```
class Tarifa(models.Model):
    limite_i = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    limite_s = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


class Calculadora(models.Model):
    tarifa = models.ForeignKey(Tarifa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    base = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    limite = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

Tengo un primer queryset que obitiene la información una fila de mi modelo Calculadora:

```
qsl1 = Calculadora.objects.values_list('base')
```

Este queryset me regresa todos los montos que tengo en base:

```
<QuerySet [(Decimal('3000.00'),), (Decimal('5000.00'),), (Decimal('1000.00'),)]>
```

Posteriormente ingreso este query como un subquery en el siguiente queryset:

```
qsl2 = Tarifa.objects.filter(Q(limite_s__gte=qsl1) & Q(limite_i_isr__lte=qsl1)).values_list('limite_i')
```

Este segundo queryset valúa que mi 'limite_s' >= 'base' and 'limite_i' <= 'base' y después me traiga el valor de 'limite_i

Ahora el problema es que me retorna únicamente la comparación del primer valor que es 3000.00, necesito que también me haga la comparación de 5000.00 y 1000.00 y todos los demás valores que se agreguen.

Pero no se como me podrían apoyar, muchas gracias.